# Naming a class representing a collection of objects of another class

Tags: naming

This is always a problem for me. Say, in a game, there's a class representing an enemy spacecraft named `EnemySpacecraft` and there's a class representing some collection of those, say all that exist in the game. This class may be implemented as just an encapsulated array of enemy spacecrafts. Giving this class a name like `EnemySpacecrafts` is way too similar to the singular form. My other ideas are e.g. `AllEnemySpacecrafts` or `EnemySpacecraftCollection`, but I don't know how good I would say those are. What is a proper name to give here? Is there a convention I'm unaware of?

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why you need a new class for this collection, rather than using a built-in collection type. (Also the platform you're working on.)

Comment: Adding an 's' to the end of a class name is a perfectly good way to indicate a collection of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the worse part of this job. Naming things.

Here some suggestions

**1. Reusability**

Let's say you want to reuse the concept of groups for different entities of the game.

You could use a basic name alongside generics

```
- Raid<>:
  - Raid<EnemySpacecraft>
- Party<>
  - Party<EnemySpacecraft>
- Fleet<>
  ...
```

They also remain loyal to the game's jargon (God, how I miss MMOs).

**2. Concreteness**

- EnemySpacecraftRaid
- EnemySpacecraftParty
- EnemySpacecraftFleet

One benefit of omitting the suffix *Collection* is that you don't tie the name solely to the idea of having just a collection. A `Raid<?>` might involve behaviours and attributes like any other entity in the game, not only `.iterator()`, `.get(int)`, `add()`, `remove()` and so on so forth.

What I like about this approach is it applies **the ubiquitous language** of the domain (games) to the code.

On the other hand, if you want everything to be subordinated to the technical language, then...

> there's a class representing some collection of those, **say all that
> exist in the game**.

The ideal name would be *EnemySpacecraftRepository*. But I get the feeling that this name doesn't meet your expectations. Right?

Comment: strictly speaking I think the plural would fit the ubiquitous language better

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to clearly separate what the list **is representing** from what a particular **instance is being used for**.
Using Java syntax, a collection of spacecraft could be as simple as

```
List<Spacecraft> activeEnemies = ...
List<Spacecraft> enemyAttackForce = ...
List<Spacecraft> surrenderedEnemies = ...
List<Spacecraft> destroyedEnemies = ...
```

If a list of enemy spacecraft has methods that make sense only for enemy craft, then by all means write a class that encapsulates that behaviour. But don't mix the concepts. EnemySpaceCrafts and EnemySpaceCraftCollection are OK names, if a little clumsy (I don't have a better suggestion). AllEnemySpaceCraft is not so good, as it suggests you should not reuse the class when you need another unrelated collection of enemy spacecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it way to similar to the singular form?  I much prefer plural and singular forms to differentiate - I guess I have my mind trained to look for the 's', but I'm also a big fan of keeping junk out of names.

I wouldn't want to see 'Collection' post-fixed to a name...  That's a big word. skimming through my code and my mind's going to want to think *hey that's a big word, we should pay attention to it* before I have a chance to think 'oh that's just a plural form represented with 9 more letters than necessary.  It's clutter.

```
enemySpacecraft
enemySpacecrafts
```

One is singular, the other is plural.  I don't think it can get much more simple than that!

Keep in mind that code context also helps:

```
craft.Fire();
crafts.Each(x => x.Fire());
```

Adding anything more is just getting in the way.  Less is more, as they say.

(disregard the fact that 'spacecraft' is actually a singular and plural word... perhaps a poor example for the topic, but you get the idea)

Answer (score -3):

I love to think of an item as a collection of one. I support this notion by implementing methods that work on collections with supplemental methods to handle scalars; purely for **syntactic sugar**. The scalar method seldom does little more than to call its counterpart. The method that works on the collection does all the work to harness the power if code re-usability, yesss!

If I implement this.**rows**([] item) I will more likely also have this.**row**(int item).  I have used this design pattern for almost two decades and no complaints yet. The reason is not brevity, coolness or magic but rather **consistency**. If you have the discipline to be consistent you cannot go wrong with any reasonable style that you choose.

I find simplicity to be of utmost elegance so i save all my energy for super elaborate **documentation** :-)

Comment: Could the downvotes explain themselves?  In many cases this is a good idea.  Note that it also allows for a collection of zero.  Depending on your language, varargs can help with this.

Comment: Maybe, because the answer doesn't respond the question. `What is a proper name to give here? Is there a convention I'm unaware of?`

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, "no there is not". Document and be consistent.

Comment: That's a better answer :-)